# Entering new data rows into SQL Server Express using C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm pretty sure I'm just being stupid here, but oh well.

My code is:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\LiftLog.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmdInsert = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblLog (Date, Time, Floor) VALUES (1011, 0011, 3)";
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It's connecting to the table, since it complains if I put no data into a not-null field. However, when I click the button, the table doesn't update.

Why?

This worked to retrieve data:

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds1;

    // Connects to database.
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        ds1 = new DataSet();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\LiftLog.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        con.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * From tblLog";
        da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds1, "LogOutput");
        NavigateRecords();
        con.Close(); 
     }
```

As SSMS won't work for me, would it be possible to modify this somehow to insert?

Also, I know about sanitising inputs etc, I stripped it all away to try and pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file (to your project's output directory where the app is run when inside Visual Studio), and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file (in your project's output directory) with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `LiftLog`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=LiftLog;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also, please note: I would **strongly recommend** always using parametrized queries to a) avoid SQL injection attacks, and b) significantly improve performance in SQL Server.

So instead of:

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblLog (Date, Time, Floor) 
                         VALUES (1011, 0011, 3)";
```

you should use

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblLog (Date, Time, Floor) 
                         VALUES (@Date, @Time, @Floor)";
```

and then define those parameters (`@Date, @Time, @Floor`) on your `SqlCommand` object and fill in their values that way.

Comment: Also his `INSERT INTO tblLog (Date, Time, Floor) VALUES (1011, 0011, 3)` doesn't look inserting correct values (if first two cols are DATETIME, DATE or TIME datatypes)

Comment: @Kaf: that might be an additional problem - not to mention one should always use **parametrized queries** and not specify values directly...

Comment: @marc_s Welp, SSMS failed to install. Inside the project's files, there is the "LiftLog.mdf" database, can I somehow link directly to that? Also, I've updated the original post with information on a dataset reading command that worked perfectly.

Comment: @Jake: you should be able to open that `.mdf` in the Visual Studio 2010 Server Explorer and peek inside...

Comment: Yes. I did. It's the one I've been reading data from + modifying, but apparently not updating.